# How to get data value of object JSON string?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a JSON string , I want to get value of JSON string property.I try

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../BUS/WebService.asmx/GET_TRANSACTION_NEW",
    data: JSON.stringify(DTO),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        var obj = $.parseJSON(data.d);
        alert(obj.TRANSACTION_NAME);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```

But it gets error `undefined` . I use  `jQuery-2.1.3.min.js`

Comment: Use `console.log(data);` and post your json data...

Comment: *"but it's get error undefined"* What does that mean? Are you getting `undefined` in the `alert`? Or are you really getting an error? We can't tell you how to access your structure if we don't know what it looks like. Given that you are the only one that can actually run the code, you are the best person to debug it. Learn how to debug, so that you can help yourself: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: I get error in alert , it's show `undefined` . JSON data as `{"d":"[{\"FULL_NAME\":\"Android\",\"TRANSACTION_NAME\":\"Lisence\",\"FLAG\":false}]"}`

Comment: Well, `d` is an array. The array doesn't have a `TRANSACTION_NAME` property. The first element it contains has that property.

Answer (score 0):

`$.parseJSON` is not needed, jQuery parses the json automatically if you specify it as the contentType.

Comment: Right, hence `data` is the parsed response. But apparently `data.d` contains JSON as well? Who knows...

Comment: Give me advice about this issue . Thank guys